# Webkit and Safari fire mousemove even when mouse doesn't move

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mousemove

I've read about issues where the `mousemove` event is fired twice in Safari/Webkit, but the problem I'm facing is that `mousemove` fires even when the mouse is **not** moved. That is: it already fires when the mouse cursor is positioned above the context that the event is attached to when the page is loaded/refreshed. And because I'm attaching it to `document` (entire viewport of the browser), it fires right away in Safari. I've tried to attach it to the `html` element, to the `body` and to a wrapper `div`. No change.

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function() {
  alert('Mouse moved!');
  $(document).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

Is does work ok in other browsers. Anyone seeing what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Cmd, ctrl alt, shift and caps lock also fires the mousemove event (safari 4 on mac). Try it out here: http://www.quirksmode.org//js/events/mousemove.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it’s a dirty hack, but at least this is something: simply execute the callback function the second time `mousemove` is fired.

```
var $document = $(document), i = 0;
$document.bind('mousemove', function() {
 if (++i > 1) {
  alert('Mouse moved!');
  $document.unbind('mousemove');
 };
});
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Yz5Bd/show/light/

For what it’s worth, Safari is not the only browser firing `mousemove` on page load — IE does it too. Anyhow, people using other browsers won’t notice the ‘delay’, since it’s virtually impossible to move your mouse only one pixel.